# using csvJDBC with mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, csvjdbc

I want to execute Select query on CSV file using csvJDBC with MapReduce.

I'm using the following code in a Map-Only function, but the output file is empty:

```
         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Load the driver.
            try {
                Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");
                // Create a connection. The first command line parameter is
                // the directory containing the .csv files.
               String csv1 = csv.substring(0, csv.indexOf("file.csv"));
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:" + csv1);

                // Create a Statement object to execute the query with.
                // A Statement is not thread-safe.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


                ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(input);

                // Dump out the results to a CSV file with the same format
                // using CsvJdbc helper function

                while (results.next())
                  {

                      out.set(results.getString("id")); 
                      context.write( out, new IntWritable(1));
                  }

                // Clean up
                conn.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: How are you submitting your map-reduce job ? Moreover how have you configured input to your map job ?

Comment: I'm using the statement as follow to execute Map job `hadoop jar /projets/test/exp.jar expl.Csvclass files/file.csv fileoutput select place from file` where the `input` variable will take the query `select place from file` from the  command line

Comment: And do you have records in "files/file.csv"

Comment: yes I have records the output is:  `Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=47
                Map output records=0
                Input split bytes=119
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=56
                CPU time spent (ms)=860`

Comment: have you tried putting any debugging statements in map() just to make sure it indeed is getting called ?

Comment: `INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1469547325715_0042 running in uber mode : false
16/09/03 11:08:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/09/03 11:08:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/09/03 11:08:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1469547325715_0042 completed successfully
16/09/03 11:08:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30 `

Comment: when I make the execution query into the main class i have recieved the following message: `ClassNotFoundException: org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver` . the program didn't accept the csvJDBC !!!

Comment: Look up the logs for job id mentioned above to see if it also shows the exception stack trace. Moreover are you bundling the required JAR in hadoop jar as well. Also try putting some system.out or logger statements in your method to trace the error.